# Send command to open process in Shell file

Tags: bash, shell

In bash how can I issue a command to a running process I just started?

For example;

```
# Start Bluez gatttool then Connect to bluetooth device 
gatttool -b $MAC -I
connect # send 'connect' to the gatttool process?
```

Currently my shell script doesn't get to the `connect` line because the `gatttool` process is running.

Comment: perhaps you are looking to send to stdin of the process

Comment: maybe http://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to send the string "connect\n" to the process, you can use a standard pipe:

```
echo "connect" | gatttool -b $MAC -I
```

If you want to engage in a more complex "conversation" with the `gatttool` process, take a look at the [`expect (1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) and [`chat (8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chat) tool, which allow you to send a sequence of strings, and wait for certain responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer a slightly "lighter" way of piping you could use a heredoc such as in:

```
gatttool -b $MAC -I <<EOF
connect
(...)
EOF
```

Everything contained between the two EOF tags will be piped to the command's input. I believe this will not allow you to interact with the command whilst between the EOF tags so, as mentioned in the previous answer, you might want to consider using expect if you need to act upon the commands' output before sending something back to it.